# Rewriting query to format sql results differently

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following query to get the number of products of various types available on each day of a week.

```
select product_type, availDate, quantity 
from myTable 
where availDate between '2013-02-15' and '2013-02-21' 
order by product_type, availDate
```

This gives the follow results...

```
product_type  |  availDate  |  quantity
--------------|-------------|----------
type1         |  2013-02-15 |  2
type1         |  2013-02-17 |  1
type1         |  2013-02-18 |  1
type1         |  2013-02-21 |  3
type2         |  2013-02-15 |  1
type2         |  2013-02-16 |  2
type2         |  2013-02-17 |  1
type2         |  2013-02-18 |  2
type2         |  2013-02-19 |  1
type2         |  2013-02-20 |  1
```

How I actually want to display it is like this:

```
product_type  | 2013-02-15 | 2013-02-16 | 2013-02-17 | 2013-02-18 | 2013-02-19 | 2013-02-20 | 2013-02-21
--------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|-----------
type1         | 2          | -          | 1          | 1          | -          | -          | 3
type2         | 1          | 2          | 1          | 2          | 1          | 1          | -
```

Is it possible to do this from the query or do I need to manipulate my results by some other means.??

Thanks

EDIT:

Now been told this is needed in Oracle SQL

Comment: It can be done with a fixed, known set of dates in SQL statement.  If the set of dates is not known, you must construct the SQL statement dynamically with a loop. That can be done either with a stored procedure, or in your application code.

Comment: The set of dates is known at the point of running the query, yes... so how would I write it in this case??

Comment: but it isn't really known in that it is a static string. You know your range at runtime, but for it to work without a dynamic loop you must know all the output columns at compile time.  What are you using on the application side?

Comment: Look over [some of these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+dynamic+pivot+table)

Comment: @Tom What is the schema? (a.k.a. type of availDate?)

Comment: availDate is a Date column

Comment: It doesn't have to be done for a known set of dates @Michael, but it can only be done for a known _number_ of dates; whatever they might be.

Comment: Would you consider formatting it with type across the top rather than date. If you've only got two types it will be considerably easier...

Comment: @ben It needs to be the way I've shown above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `PIVOT` query, the disadvantage of this simple version is that you need to list all interesting dates in the query;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT "product_type", "availDate", "quantity" 
  FROM myTable 
)
SELECT * FROM cte
PIVOT (SUM("quantity") AS Quantity for ("availDate") IN
       ('15-Feb-2013',
        '16-Feb-2013',
        '17-Feb-2013',
        '18-Feb-2013',
        '19-Feb-2013'))
ORDER BY "product_type"
```

[SQLfiddle for testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/df01a1/5).

Comment: How can I replace NULL values with a "-" using this method?? It's not as simple as I thought it would be with NVL(......

Comment: You could try casting the dates to (n)(var)char(2) and then try NVL.  It will be less flexible/efficient, however, and apply it to Joachim's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it's any help at all, I did find this...
http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78

May be useful.

Kind regards,
Westie.

Comment: This question is for Oracle and yet you posted a link to MySQL queries, this does not answer the question.

Comment: I edited the question after he'd posted this reply so this response was once more than valid...

Comment: If the answer I've given is no longer valid then it can be deleted.